# How to extract multiple ints from string and append to dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` that looks like

```
Pairing        Result
1001_1234_1235 1
1001_1233_1236 0
...
```

I want to extract the final 2 ints for each row in the `Pairing` column and place them into new columns. That is, I want `df` to now look like

```
Pairing        Result  First Second
1001_1234_1235 1       1234  1235
1001_1233_1236 0       1233  1236
...
```

Anyone know how?

Comment: Why is this tagged regex?

Comment: Using regex for string operations is not a too far fetched idea, although it's certainly not necessary in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do that with the pandas `str` operations:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Pairing': ['1001_1234_1235', '1001_1233_1236'],
    'Result': [1, 0],
})

# split at '_', each result will become a new column
df2 = df['Pairing'].str.split('_', expand=True)

# convert to numbers
df2 = df2.astype(int)

#rename columns back to something useful
df2.columns = ['Pairing{}'.format(col) for col in df2.columns ]

# add the columns back to the old DataFrame
df = df.join(df2)
```

This results in:

```
          Pairing  Result  Pairing0  Pairing1  Pairing2
0  1001_1234_1235       1      1001      1234      1235
1  1001_1233_1236       0      1001      1233      1236
```

See Pandas – Working with Text Data for more examples:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html

Answer (score 0):

if you have `pairing = '1001_1234_1235'` then

```
first = pairing.split("_")[-2]
second = pairing.split("_")[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# assuming you have defined other columns in df here

# Create empty columns for the new int columns
df['First'] = np.NaN
df['Second'] = np.NaN

# For each element in Pairing
for i, pairing in enumerate(df['Pairing']):
    # split pairing into list based on underscores, get last two ints only
    ints = [int(x) for x in pairing.split('_')[-2:]]
    df['First'][i] = ints[0]
    df['Second'][i] = ints[1]

print(df)
```

New `df` should look like:

```
Pairing          Result  First  Second
1001_1234_1235   1       1234   1235
1001_1233_1236   0       1233   1236
...
```